# Window Service to send autogenerated mail on the basis of a field in the dataBase

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I need to create a window service that will check a Date field in the database and on the basis of that date it will send an auto generated mail. 
  I am new in the field of Window service. 
   So Please help me by suggesting some good examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Creating a Windows service in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y300).
- [Database connection (and email) from Windows service in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540230/unable-to-execute-sql-command-in-windows-service).
- [Sending an email from a Windows service in VB](http://msmvps.com/blogs/joacim/archive/2009/09/13/creating-a-windows-service-using-vb-net.aspx).